# PHP find which file a Constant was initially defined?

Tags: php, debugging, constants

I am just wondering if its possible to find where a constant <strike>is being redefined</strike> was initially defined? Turning on `display_errors` to `E_ALL` will just throw `Notice` where a constant was being redefined, but it did not say which file/function it was initially defined.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The file/function and line number mentioned in the Notice message is where the constant is defined for the second time.
( although I can understand that one can could interpret this message differently.)

`Notice: Constant SES_REGION already defined in  <php-file> on line 7`

To be clear: the notice does NOT say where the constant was originally defined.
Is says where it is redefined.

Comment: you're actually right, then I guess the question should be get which file/function the constant was initially defined.

Comment: I would search my source files for `define('MY_CONSTANT'` with grep or grepWin.

Comment: I tried, now I suspect there's a function that was called that assigns a constant to its value.